# How to use a swift library in kotlin native?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

How can I use a Swift Library in Kotlin/Native?

I was trying out cinteropt to use objective-c libraries in `Kotlin/Native` but I can't seem to figure out how I could use a swift library?

Can anyone guide me here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, which extension is your swift library? you cana ctually use ```.so``` libraries if they target the device archtecture (arm-abi, x86-64, etc) and use C++ JNI binding (with the original header files from the library) to call it. But you will will program mostly in C++ this aprt not Kotlin

Comment: Sorry, my answer was for Android target, but maybe my commentary can enlighten in your search

Comment: it actually confused me more. Please help me out. The only reason I want to use a swift library so I could use it for my ios targets. Thats it. Specifically, I am trying to use a swift library wrapper for keychain so I could create a library which uses Keychain for ios and Encrypted SharedPreference in Android. For Android, its easy but I can't figure out how to do it with swift.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't interop with Swift directly, unless the Swift is designed to be consumed by Objective-C. I assume the Keychain library has Objective-C bindings available, which you should be able to interop with. If not, you can either write some kind of wrapper that would expose an Objective-C interface, or write a Kotlin interface and implement it in Swift, and pass that in to shared code.

Comment: If a library already exposes its api with `@objC` , does generating a binary of it allows it to interopt with Kotlin/Native? or are there additional steps to take for this to work?